# Rails 3 Conditions on Eager Loaded Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, eager-loading

I'm having trouble with Rails 3 using conditions on an associated table while eager loading. It appears that Rails is applying the condition when it loads the original model data, so it won't load the parent model unless a non-zero number of the child/associated models match the condition. This is easier to explain in code (simplified for example):

```
@post = Post.includes(:comments).where(:comments => { :approved => true }).find(1)
```

This would generate a SQL query similar to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `posts`.id FROM `posts`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `comments` ON `comments`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id`
WHERE (`comments`.`approved` = 1) AND (`posts`.`id` = '1')
LIMIT 1
```

In the case that there aren't any comments that meet the `approved = 1` condition, no rows are returned, and thus the Post never gets loaded at all.

**What is the right way to load a post and the associated comments eagerly with a condition on the comments?**

#### Update

I'd stil love to hear a better way of doing this, but for now I'm using the following to work around it (works with deeply nested eager loading):

```
@post = Post.find(1)
@comments = @post.comments.where(:approved => true).all

# allows deeper/more complex nesting without getting into SQL:
@post = Post.includes(:author => [ :websites, :photo ]).find(1)
@comments = @post.comments.includes(:editor).where(:approved => true).all
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: There might be some nugget of wisdom in [this post on includes vs eager_load vs preload](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html).

I'd still love to hear a better way of doing this, but for now I'm using the following to work around it (works with deeply nested eager loading, unlike using `joins`):

```
@post = Post.find(1)
@comments = @post.comments.where(:approved => true).all

# allows deeper/more complex nesting without getting into SQL:
@post = Post.includes(:author => [ :websites, :photo ]).find(1)
@comments = @post.comments.includes(:editor).where(:approved => true).all
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is `joins` method, it will let you put your condition within join definition, not outside of it. For example:

```
@post = Post.joins("LEFT JOIN comments on posts.id = comments.post_id AND comments.approved = 1").first
```

Not sure about the correctness of the condition itself but you get my point.

Unfortunately you have to use that ugly string as `joins` is using INNER JOIN if you pass array/hash.

There's more [about `joins` at rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)

Comment: This doesn't really work for me because I'm actually doing more than a single level of eager loading. That winds up rather verbose when using joins. I'm avoiding the problem all together right now by making a second call to grab the nested data (like comments).